# Jenkins Warnings Plugin Slow

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

A Jenkins job (a moderately complex Maven multimodule Java project) which used to take about 4 hours to run has been profiled. The first thing that popped out is that the sum of the times in the Maven reactor was definitely lower than the total time. It turned out that the culprit was the Warnings plugin, which runs with a couple of custom rules. With the plugin disabled, the job takes about 45 minutes to complete (a duration which now matches the Maven reactor times).

Googling around I've found similar issues, but one in 2012 is marked as fixed, and another discussion in 2015 didn't come to a conclusion.

Is it a known problem still today? Can it be worked around with anything better than disabling the plugin?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps, though ~1.5 years older, the [Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin)/[Console Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Console+Parser+Plugin) is an alternative. Do the logs reside on the same machine (HDD) the job is running on and not on a different slave (such avoiding access of a large 45min-job log file over the network)? If so already - and if it's not a solvable SW issue -, storing the log on an SSD increases performance significantly in general. Can you please link the similar issues you found.

Comment: The two references I found are: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/DnchkYUubwA and https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14383

Comment: For what concerns slaves: the job was originally on a slave, and a copy is now running on the master (we are in the process of converting from Hudson to Jenkins and from a Windows Server + Linux slave to a singe Linux server: we have temporarily both approaches, and we can compare them). I'm aware that slaves have the problem of possibly moving lots of things back to the server. In any case, both jobs were comparably slow with the plugin enabled, and comparably fast with the plugin disabled.